# Angular/RxJS - Converting a promise and inner observable to one single observable to be returned

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a promise that, once it's fulfilled, creates and subscribes to an observable. What I need to do is instead convert this promise to an observable and return this observable for subscription elsewhere (which would include the inner observable). I used `from` to convert the promise to an observable and then used `concatMap` to chain the inner observable. However, at the beginning of the `concatMap`, I'm getting an error in my code for the `xfdfString` string variable that I'm trying to retrieve from the initial promise. Perhaps my new function's inner observable is not actually returning an observable itself? I've tried a few things to resolve this with no luck, so any ideas would be much appreciated.

Error:

```
Argument of type '(xfdfString: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.ts(2345)
```

Original function:

```
  save() {
    const { annotManager } = this.wvInstance;
    annotManager.exportAnnotations({ links: false, widgets: false }).then(xfdfString => {
      const requestId = (<SignatureDocumentData>this.task.actionData).requestId;
      const data: SignDocument = { encodedDocument: encodeBase64(xfdfString) };

      this.documentService.signDocument(requestId, data)
        .pipe(
          switchMap(signResponse => this.workflowService.completeAction(this.task.id)),
          switchMap(nextTask => {
            if (!nextTask) {
              return this.workflowService.completeFolder();
            } else {
              return observableOf(nextTask);
            }
          }),
        ).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
    });
  }
```

My attempt at using a higher-order observable to instead return one observable:

```
save(): Observable<any> {
  const { annotManager } = this.wvInstance;

  const docViewerobservable = from(annotManager.exportAnnotations({ links: false, widgets: false }));

  return docViewerobservable.pipe(
    concatMap(xfdfString => {
      const requestId = (<SignatureDocumentData>this.task.actionData).requestId;
      let data = { encodedDocument: encodeBase64(xfdfString) };
      

      this.documentService.signDocument(requestId, data)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(signResponse => this.workflowService.completeAction(this.task.id)),
        switchMap(nextTask => {
          if (!nextTask) {
            return this.workflowService.completeFolder();
          } else {
            return observableOf(nextTask);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to return the Observable that you've created inside `concatMap` ;-)

```
save(): Observable<any> {
  const { annotManager } = this.wvInstance;

  const docViewerobservable = from(annotManager.exportAnnotations({ links: false, widgets: false }));

  return docViewerobservable.pipe(
    concatMap(xfdfString => {
      const requestId = (<SignatureDocumentData>this.task.actionData).requestId;
      let data = { encodedDocument: encodeBase64(xfdfString) };
      

      return this.documentService.signDocument(requestId, data)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(signResponse => this.workflowService.completeAction(this.task.id)),
        switchMap(nextTask => {
          if (!nextTask) {
            return this.workflowService.completeFolder();
          } else {
            return observableOf(nextTask);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Otherwise, it looks good!

Comment: Ah!! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!!